# Rewrite rule in .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, recursion

I have already spent a lot of time to create a rewrite rule in .htaccess but without luck so far. Is there any genius to help me please?

I would like to rewrite this URL:

`http://www.domain.com/all-players/Spain-Real-Madrid.php?playername=Cristiano+Ronaldo+dos+Santos+Aveiro`

into this one:

`http://www.domain.com/Spain-Real-Madrid-Cristiano-Ronaldo-dos-Santos-Aveiro-player.html`

Changes are:

1. remove the level /all-players
2. concat Spain-Real-Madrid with Cristiano+Ronaldo+dos+Santos+Aveiro (and add an hyphen in between)
3. convert + into - in the value of the parameter playername
4. add the word '-player' before the file extension

Another example is to convert this path:

`/all-players/England-Arsenal.php?playername=Thierry+Henry`

into:

`/England-Arsenal-Thierry-Henry-player.html`

Thanks heaps,

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR, there's no way to do this in one Regexp. Therefore, you'll need to get it in several steps.
Most probably the following will not work just copy-pasted, cause I'm not very experienced in rewrites.

```
RewriteRule /all-players/(.*?)\.php?playername=(.*) /all-players-1/$1-$2


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^/all-players-1/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \+
RewriteRule \+ -


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^/all-players-1/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[^+]+$
RewriteRule /all-players-1/(.*)  /$1-player.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **recusrion based** rule that will do what you need:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^playername=(.*)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^all-players/([^\.]+)\.php$ /$1-%1-player.html? [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^([^+]+)\+([^+]+)(\+.*)?$ $1-$2$3 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^([^+])\+ $1 [R,L]
```

This code will **recursively replace** all the `+` signs with hyphens `-`.

This will **externally redirect**:

- `/all-players/England-Arsenal.php?playername=Thierry+Henry` to `/England-Arsenal-Thierry-Henry-player.html`
- `/Spain-Real-Madrid.php?playername=Cristiano+Ronaldo+dos+Santos+Aveiro` to `/Spain-Real-Madrid-Cristiano-Ronaldo-dos-Santos-Aveiro-player.html`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I've tried it but it looks like it doesn't do the redirection. I have tested on the website http://htaccess.madewithlove.be but without luck. Is there any online tool where I can test it please?. When I apply it on my local server, I have this following error: [an error occurred while processing this directive]. Can you please advise or comment your code please? Thanks heaps for your help!

Comment: Ok comment out last 2 RewriteRule lines and see what happens. It should **Internally** redirect `/all-players/England-Arsenal.php?playername=Thierry+Henry` to /England-Arsenal-Thierry+Henry-player.html`

Comment: Ok, there likely to be a conflict with the rule I already have. Here it is: RewriteRule ^/(.*)\.html$ /redirect.php?param=$1 How can I use your rules and mine at the same time? Mine takes an html file as input and pass some value to a PHP file which handle those values. So it means that someone who use the URL as HTML or as php (same examples provided above with Ronaldo Cristiano) will be redirected to a PHP file called redirect. And lastly, I forgot to mention I'd like to do a permanent redirect for the PHP format mentioned initially in my post (examples with Ronaldo and Henry). Thanks heaps!

Comment: About permanent redirect you can change flag `R` to `R=301` and it will be permanent redirect. About your conflicting rule I would suggest to use slightly different extension `.htm` for my proposed rule i.e. `/England-Arsenal-Thierry-Henry-player.htm` instead of `/England-Arsenal-Thierry-Henry-player.html`.